# Printing from a different tray in cups

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print from tray 2 but I can only print from tray 1 and there is no way to enable more paper sources in cups is there a way to enable this option?

My printer is a Epson xp950.

Comment: What is your printer?

Comment: Epson xp950. Sorry.

Comment: Did you install drivers for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install full feature drivers and the printer utility.

Go to [Epson drivers site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

Search for you printer and download Printer driver 1.0.0 and Printer utility: `epson-inkjet-printer-201305w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`, `epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`.

Copy these files to your home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The setting is here

[image]

Comment: still no option to select paper source cups is version 1.7.2

Comment: Look at the picture.

Comment: I have that option already im trying to change the paper tray but i have no options.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B036ksGKW5QpQXJjY21xQ2s4WkE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Even with installed official utility for printer (in my case Lexmark) I was not able to print from tray 2, even if I would select "proper" option. What helped in my case was changing command syntax.

before on Ubuntu12

```
lp -o media=a4,Tray2 <FILE_TO_PRINT>
```

now on Ubuntu16

```
lp -o media=A4 -o InputSlot=Tray2 <FILE_TO_PRINT>
```